# PostgreSQL timestamptz(variable) : type modifiers must be simple constants or identifiers

Tags: postgresql

I would like to set the precision in a [timestamptz(*p*)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) where *p* is a variable instead of a constant.

Like this:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE precision int = 3;
BEGIN SELECT now()::timestamptz(precision);
END; $$;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "precision"
LINE 1: SELECT now()::timestamptz(precision)
                      ^
```

The same error occurs when precision has a type of int2, int4, and int8 (and any other number type).

This error seams to be more helpful:

```sql
# SELECT now()::timestamptz(3::int);
ERROR:  type modifiers must be simple constants or identifiers
LINE 1: SELECT now()::timestamptz(3::int);
                      ^
```

Do you know of anyway to do this with a variable just short of conditionally executing the more hard-coded precision constant version?

I have several places I need to set the precision to 3 if the date is coming from an API (node's ISO date has less precision) and leave it at 6 when the dates are all from the database.

Just to show how it typically works:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT now()::timestamptz(6);
              now              
-------------------------------
 2023-05-20 18:29:23.915378+00
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT now()::timestamptz(3);
            now             
----------------------------
 2023-05-20 18:29:27.263+00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go dynamic per [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    precision int = 3;
    time_val timestamptz;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT now()::timestamptz(' || precision || ')' into time_val;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Time is: %', time_val;
END; $$;

NOTICE:  Time is: 05/20/2023 15:25:59.548 PDT
DO
```

FYI, a `date` does not have precision value, so assuming you are actually talking about a datetime/timestamp:

```
select '2023-05-20 15:26:32.123456'::timestamptz(6);
          timestamptz           
--------------------------------
 05/20/2023 15:26:32.123456 PDT

select '2023-05-20 15:26:32.123'::timestamptz(6);
         timestamptz         
-----------------------------
 05/20/2023 15:26:32.123 PDT

select '2023-05-20 15:26:32.123'::timestamptz(3);
         timestamptz         
-----------------------------
 05/20/2023 15:26:32.123 PDT
```

I am not seeing that changing the precision changes anything.

Comment: Lowering the precision is required to compare a date after a round-trip to node and back..

Comment: 1) You are not comparing a date, you are comparing a datetime(timestamp). 2) If Node is sending a datetime with only 3 decimal places I don't see Postgres changing that as per above, so you will get only 3 decimal places back.

Comment: a) Yes, I meant to say timestamptz.  Fyi, PostgreSQL rounds and JavaScript truncates, so I ended up using `date_trunc` instead and this logic: -- When microseconds ends in three zeros, the date is likely to be from node (javascript) with a lower precision (in milliseconds).  Reducing the precision only when the microseconds ends in 3 zeros allows comparison with a 1:1000 chance of unnecessary loss of precision.

Comment: b) `DECLARE precision text = 'microseconds'; BEGIN IF(EXTRACT(MICROSECONDS FROM NEW.updated_at) % 1000 = 0) THEN precision = 'milliseconds'; END IF;` ... `IF date_trunc(precision, NEW.updated_at) <> date_trunc(precision, now()) ...`.